# How to get access to data in roo Vue instance?

Tags: vue.js, dexie

I have found [wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-idb) for Working with IndexDB. But I can't understand how to access to `idb` from my component. Here is example from docs:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueIdb from 'vue-idb'
 
Vue.use(VueIdb)
 
const idb = new VueIdb({
  version: 1,
  database: 'test',
  schemas: [
    { tests: 'id, title, created_at, updated_at' },
        { posts: 'id, owner' }
  ]
})
 
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  idb: idb,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

In my component I tried to do:

```
axios.get(base_url + '/api/industry')
        .then((response) => {
          idb.test= response.data; // here
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

Is there any way to declare IndexDB inside my component?

But it do not working.

Comment: The tests in the repository use vm.$db.  Have your tried this.$db or vm.$db?

Comment: https://github.com/ddgll/vue-idb/blob/master/test/specs/idb.spec.js

Comment: it('sets the correct default data', () => {
    expect(vm.$db).to.be.an('object')
  })

Comment: Why it use name `db` while variable named `idb`?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know, but did my suggestion help?

Comment: `this.$db.test = response.data;`  works. But I can't understand where to use shema name? Like `tests` from example.